# How to listen window rotation finished in android?

Tags: android, android-orientation

In my app, I need to do some action when screen orientation change.
So I do following work:

```
//in AndroidManifest.xml
<!-- SomeSetting -->
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name="MainActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

//in MainActivity.java
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        doSomething();
    }
```

Here is my question:
I want to call `doSomething()` "after" Orientation Animation(like rotate or crossfade) finish. But it will be call right after animation start.
Is there a listener or something can listen to this kind of animation finish?

**Update 0223**

FYI:

After my experiments, I found that `OnConfigurationChange` is not reliable enough.
I will use `View.addOnLayoutChangeListener` to get attribute (View is the component which I want to read value from). Then I can make sure the value is after orientation. By the way, I still need to override `OnConfigurationChange` to avoid recreate whole view.
You may google `addOnLayoutChangeListener()` to learn how to use it.

Comment: Would you like to explain what actually u want to do? Because there is no native callback for what u r asking.

Comment: @chandil03 Thanks for reply. I have to change a view's layout. Actually if I call `doSomething()` delayed 0.1 second using TimerTask, it will work fine. But I'm trying to find a more general solution.

Comment: which view's layout you want to change, can u be more specific?

Comment: SurfaceView's width & height.

Comment: Also I'm using a sdk which will render on the SurfaceView. So the flow become quite complicated.

Comment: I can help u if you can give your MainActivity.java code.

Comment: I afraid I can't provide detail code. Can you give me any hint?

Comment: Ok,... check my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help. I found in my `doSomething()` I forgot to update SurfaceViewHolder, so the surfaceView seem strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, what do you want is your `doSomeThing()` method should be called when view is drawn on layout.

So you need to use `View.post()` method to achieve that.
Have a look at following ex:

```
fab.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something here 
            //......
            //......
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Orientation has changed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Here fab is a view on which you want to perform operation when it is drawn on screen (So u do not need to use `TimerTask`).

So as you told you want to update `SurfaceView` when orientation is changed. You can use `post` method of surface view(like `fab` in above code).

Comment: It's my stupid bug. But this seems to be the best answer so far.

Answer (score -1):

Your `onCreate()` method will be fired after your Orientation change.
Therefore,in your case you can call `doSomeThing()` inside `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      doSomething();
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have to keep activity remain during configure change. I thought this line `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` will prevent onCreate being fired.

Comment: can you check this method `public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState); 
}`. does it fired after orientation change or not

Comment: I've check this. `OnRestoreInstanceState` didn't fire. Maybe configChanges will chenge normal flow I guess.

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If you want more information you can see the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)